# How can I use plain TeX with TeXnicCenter or another IDE?

Tags: windows, plain-tex, texniccenter, ide

Currently I use TeCnicCenter and MiKTeX with LaTeX on a Windows machine.  I am contemplating using plain TeX for certain purposes.  I would like to know how to use TeXnicCenter with plain TeX.  I like TeXnicCenter, but I can use another program if I have to.  I really dislike the Windows command prompt.  If I need to switch, I am not looking for just an editor, but an IDE like TeXnicCenter, if IDE is an appropriate term here.

I want to be able to produce PDF files.  I can think of no reason I would want to make Postscript or DVI files.

I am a mathematician, not a computer person, so please over-explain if necessary.  I do not enjoy TeX or LaTeX like many people do, but it is free and I think we all agree it produces better-looking output than anything else out there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a way to do this in TeXnicCenter:

1. Visit your Output Profiles (Build > Define Output Profiles / <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>). TeXnicCenter creates a number of output profiles by default, including one called `LaTeX > PS > PDF`.

   [image]
2. Make a copy of this and call it `TeX > PS > PDF`. Then change the "Path to the (La)TeX compiler to use the `tex.exe` executable rather than `latex.exe`.

   [image]
3. Use the `TeX > PS > PDF` profile (Build > Select Output Profile) when you want to compile a TeX document to PDF.

Comment: As an additional option, follow Werners instructions, but for the profile `LaTeX->pdf`, change `pdflatex.exe` to `pdftex.exe` to bypass the `.ps` step.

Comment: @Werner : Thanks for your prompt and well-explained reply.  I will try to make it work soon.  I noticed you seem to have edited my question because I attempted to write "$\TeX$" and "$\LaTeX$".  Is it possible to use TeX in questions in this forum, like you can in Math Stack Exchange?  If not, why not?  Isn't this at least ironic?

Comment: @bogus: TeX rendering capability in this site has been turned off  because it was annoying for most users.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach with some features:

1. You can select compiler: either `pdflatex` or `pdftex`.
2. You can specify the number of compilation to get correct cross-referencing.
3. You can remove automatically unused auxiliary files.

### Step 1

Create a batch file named `MultipleDirectPdf.bat` as follows

```
rem MultipleDirectPdf.bat
echo off

rem %1 Compiler name, either pdflatex or pdftex
rem %2 TeX input filename without extension
rem %3 The number of invocation in draftmode

if exist "%~2.pdf" del "%~2.pdf"

if exist "%~2.tex" for /l %%x in (1,1,%3) do %1 -shell-escape -draftmode -interaction=batchmode "%~2.tex"
if exist "%~2.tex" %1 -shell-escape "%~2.tex"

for %%x in (aux log out toc nav snm) do (if exist "%~2.%%x" del "%~2.%%x")
```

Save it in a safe directory or make a backup for future use. **NOTE:** I deliberately enable `-shell-escape` because  I often use it. You should know it is dangerous!

### Step 2

Make new output profiles (as explained in @Werner's solution)

[image]

You can create as many output profiles as you want with the batch file. For example

- `pdftex "%tm" 3` (as used above). It will use `pdftex` compiler with 4 times compilation (3 times in draft mode and once in default mode).
- `pdflatex "%tm" 1`. It will use `pdflatex` compiler with twice compilation (once in draft mode and once in default mode).
- `pdflatex "%tm" 10000`. It will use `pdflatex` compiler with 10001 times compilation.

### Step 3

If you want to integrate Adobe Reader, do the following. Remember, you have to select the Viewer tab (red framed).

[image]

### Step 4

Finish and please say goodbye to Arara. :-)

Comment: Thanks for your instant reply and all the work you put into it.  Who is Arara?

Comment: @bogus: If you like my answer, don't forget to accept it followed by up voting it as well. Arara is a tool developed by [Paulo Cereda](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3094/paulo-cereda) to control compilation by inserting Arara's statements right before `\documentclass{}`. The batch file above does the Arara's job so I don't need to learn and use Arara in my daily life.

Comment: Thanks.  I did Google Arara, and it was the sixth link listed.  I didn't look that far.  I upvoted your answer and Werner's.  Of course I can only accept one answer.  I'll try implementing at least one of the answers I got before accepting any.