# How to run a file using amstex and amsppt packages?

Tags: amstex

I've got a file which contains the following:

```
\input amstex
\documentstyle {amsppt}
```

I've TeXnicCenter downloaded on my computer, I can open this file with it, but it doesn't want to build. Could you please help me to solve this problem?

Comment: You need to run `pdftex` on it, rather than `pdflatex`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Plain TeX for processing your file, not LaTeX.

You can find instructions to set up TeXnicCenter for running Plain TeX at [How can I use plain TeX with TeXnicCenter or another IDE?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/131970/4427)

I suggest to follow [Scott H.’s suggestion in comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131970/how-can-i-use-plain-tex-with-texniccenter-or-another-ide#comment298003_131976) for building a direct TeX → PDF engine.

Comment: It doesn't work, it gave me this message "Undefined control sequance

Comment: @RefaatSalem What's the undefined control sequence?